# LinkedIn API error 403 "Accessing the UGC resource is forbidden" using Zapier connector

Tags: linkedin-api, zapier

For the past 3 or 4 years, I've used a Zapier automation to post to my #LinkedIn personal or company pages. It's run successfully hundreds of times, and has proven a popular way of celebrating the success of my students who complete my online courses.

On 24 April, an existing zap reported an error: "Accessing the UGC resource is forbidden. Please check your permissions for this resource". All subsequent runs of this zap have resulted in the same error.

A similar zap ran successfully last week and created this post and image: https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:7052139663221788673

Further troubleshooting with Zapier Support revealed that their API is receiving a 403 error from the LinkedIn API: https://gists.security.zapier.com/gists/78b9710a-062f-4cab-9fa5-470ffa9e1480. The error includes the description "Entity blocked due to member/content being marked as a spammer/spam or blocked."

I've raised a support ticket with LinkedIn, who passed me to LinkedAds, who referred me here.

The content that the failing zap is trying to post is: "Congratulations to [Neil Benson] for completing our course, Estimating Business Applications: https://customery.com/estimating. Thanks for being part of Customery Academy. #Dynamics365 #PowerApps #PowerBI #PowerPlatform #Estimating"

And include this image: https://storage.cloudconvert.com/tasks/95dd792c-e79d-42eb-8e47-2c7be4351a24/Estimating%20Business%20Apps%20-%20Erick%20Rezende.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=cloudconvert-production&Expires=1682564471&Signature=%2BgMQ%2FLOE0OKrBb8dD5LPdnzE5O8%3D&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22Estimating%20Business%20Apps%20-%20Erick%20Rezende.jpg%22&response-content-type=image%2Fjpeg

I reconnected my Zapier account to LinkedIn to ensure the authentication token is current.

I tested a new zap posting a simple message to my company page that included my company URL and it worked. This shows that my LinkedIn account is not restricted (so far as I can tell), and that my Zapier configuration is working as expected.